# How get sum and average BigDecimal values in ireport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, bigdecimal, arithmetic-expressions

I try sum and avg arithmetic operations using ireport for BigDecimal values.
Has error anyways when i doing.

-All types are defined BigDecimal in ireport.

-In separete, variables in this example works fine, but i can't doing arithmetic operations with variables.

**How sum and average values type BigDecimal?**

In my exemple, This is not work:

```
$F{faturasAuditadasValorTotalLiberado}
.add(new BigDecimal($F{admissaoValorTotalLiberado}, new MathContext(100)))
```

I try using Java sintax in ireport, but don't work.

I'm use version 3.0.0 ireport. I can't find solution in Jaspersoft community

The default configuration sintax for expression in ireport 3.0.0 is Java

[image]

```
new Long($F{faturasAuditadasQtdDiarias}) + new Long($F{faturasAuditadasQtdDiarias})
```

I tried, but don't work:

```
new Long($F{faturasAuditadasQtdDiarias}).sum($F{faturasAuditadasQtdDiarias})


new Long($F{faturasAuditadasQtdDiarias}).sum(new Long($F{faturasAuditadasQtdDiarias}))


$F{faturasAuditadasQtdDiarias}.sum($F{faturasAuditadasQtdDiarias})


$F{faturasAuditadasQtdDiarias} + $F{faturasAuditadasQtdDiarias}
```

Comment: i solved the problem sum : $F{faturasAuditadasValorTotalCobrado}
.add($F{admissaoValorTotalCobrado}, new MathContext(100))
.add($F{altasValorTotalCobrado}, new MathContext(100))

Comment: Hi, as you solved your own question. Would it be possible to write and accept you own answer (for future reference...).

Comment: M.Doe. yes i will do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved the problem for sum :

```
 $F{faturasAuditadasValorTotalCobrado} 
.add($F{admissaoValorTotalCobrado}, new MathContext(100)) 
.add($F{altasValorTotalCobrado}, new MathContext(100))
```